# Ayuda en la consulta sql (suma)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

estoy realizando una Query en donde sume la cantidad de productos que tengo despues mutiplicarlo..

este es la Query.

```
declare @Sucursalid int
set @Sucursalid = 1
    SELECT  i.sucursalid as SucursalID,( COUNT(p.id) * p.pesomililitros) AS Cantidad
         FROM inventario AS i
         INNER JOIN productos AS p ON i.productoid = p.id
         WHERE i.sucursalid = @Sucursalid AND i.consumido = 0 AND ( i.copeo IS NULL OR i.copeo IS NOT NULL ) AND i.copeo = 1
         GROUP BY I.sucursalid, p.pesomililitros
```

ESTE ES EL RESULTADO 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando debería ser asi..

```
SucursalID    Cantidad
1             2950
```

Espero entiendan.
Gracias.

Estructura de la tabla productos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En si, el valor de pesomililitros puede ser distinta.
750ml
700ml
695ml

me indica este error. si le agrego `sum(( COUNT(p.id) * p.pesomililitros)) AS Cantidad`
En la seleccion del sql...

```
   cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery
```

Comment: ¿Podrias compartir la estructura de tus tablas? Ya que me quiero imaginar que tienes registros diferentes para el mismo producto y por eso te da cómo resultado dos registros.

Comment: Asi es, el valor de pesomililitros puede variar..

Comment: Lo que sucede es que tienes dos productos diferentes, o eso es lo que quiero pensar, tienes algo como Producto A 750 ml, Producto B 700 ml y Producto C 695 ml ?¿

Comment: Si, asi es.. estas en lo correcto, puede que tambien tengan el mismo valor del peso en mililitros

Comment: Entonces creo que para poder darle solución deberias de tener algo así Producto A 750 ml Producto A 700 ml y Producto A 695 ml , es decir el mismo producto solo con la variación de los mililitros pero siendo el mismo producto.

Comment: Bueno en si, la solucion que espero es que me pueda sumar, esa valor de pesomililitros.  independientemente que sean el mismo peso.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82429/discussion-between-m-gress-and-juanl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrias probar intentando de la linea de la siguiente forma.

```
declare @Sucursalid int
set @Sucursalid = 1

SELECT  i.sucursalid as SucursalID,
(COUNT(p.id) * SUM(p.pesomililitros)) AS Cantidad
FROM inventario AS i
INNER JOIN productos AS p ON i.productoid = p.id
WHERE i.sucursalid = @Sucursalid AND i.consumido = 0 AND ( i.copeo IS NULL OR i.copeo IS NOT NULL ) AND i.copeo = 1
GROUP BY I.sucursalid
```

Lo que se realiza en el query es contar la cantidad de registros al mismo tiempo que sumar los mililitros y despues realizar la multiplicacion, de esta forma como son funciones de agregado ya no te las pide en el groupby y puedes obtener la solucion a tu necesidad.

Saludos, espero te funcione.

Comment: No me lanza el resultado correcto ya que espero que sea. 2950 y me lanza 11800, hace la suma de 3 productos, con valores de 750 + 750 + 750 = 2250 + 700 = 2950. <- Resultado que quiero,  NO 11800

Comment: creo que necesitaria un poco mas de informacion sobre los registros que tienes en la tabla para darte la solucion correcta.

Comment: tambien lo que podrias hacer es la consulta que te arroja tu resultado meterla en un CTE de la siguiente forma ........... ;WITH cx AS (    TU CONSULTA QUE TE ARROJA LOS RESULTADOS )         SELECT SucursalID, SUM(Cantidad)
FROM cx GROUP BY SucursalID

Comment: CTE? Que significa ese termino?, igual podría probar.

Comment: Claro te explico... Un CTE es un artefacto que nos mantiene en memoria el resultado de una consulta, para que lo podamos llamar luego dentro de esa misma consulta. Es como una “variable” temporal que nos evita tener que declarar una vista no persistente, o una tabla temporal.... podeis encontrar mas documentacion sobre esto en la siguiente url : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017................ saludos.

Comment: Si me funciono.

Answer (score 1):

si lo que quieres es que solo te sume la cantidad por sucursal solo tienes que indicarle en el group by por I.sucursalid y asi te dara ese resultado, mas o menos te quedaria asi tu codigo

```
declare @Sucursalid int
set @Sucursalid = 1

SELECT  i.sucursalid as SucursalID,
SUM(COUNT(p.id) * p.pesomililitros) AS Cantidad
FROM inventario AS i
INNER JOIN productos AS p ON i.productoid = p.id
WHERE i.sucursalid = @Sucursalid AND i.consumido = 0 AND ( i.copeo IS NULL OR i.copeo IS NOT NULL ) AND i.copeo = 1
GROUP BY I.sucursalid
```

Comment: en si, es el mismo query que puse en la descripcion, y el resultado es la que presente en el problema

Comment: @JuanL pero te funciono

Comment: No es el resultado que espero.

Comment: @JuanL pero muestra el resultado

Comment: no amigo, CORRECION... NO FUNCIONA, ME INDICA ESTE ERROR. Column 'productos.PesoMililitros' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @por que debes de poner es un SUM no un COUNT

Comment: Cambiar el count en por un sum en p.id, lo que haria es sumarme las id

Comment: Edite la pregunta hay debe de funcionarte